# How can I override Firefox readonly input default cursor?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an html input element that has `readonly` attribute active. On Chrome, I can override the default cursor by CSS like this:

```
input:read-only {
    cursor: text;
}
```

But this does not affect Firefox's cursor behaviour. How can I change Firefox's cursor as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only) you need to use `:-moz-read-only` for Firefox.

```
input:-moz-read-only { cursor: text; }
input:read-only { cursor: text; }
```